# does using Sequalize.Op.eq prevent sql injections or should input also be normalized?

Tags: node.js, security, sequelize.js, sql-injection, normalization

I'm using nodejs, express and sequlize to display a form and save it to a databse. As I'm new to backend I would like to make sure the data saved to a db is safe.

As stated in the title, is it enought to use `Seqlelize.Op.eq` to prevent SQL injection or should some other technique (such as normalize) also be used?

What the app does is process the user input for "typos" and underlines incorrect usage and gives explanations as to why it's wrong.

So, the data which will be saved to the db will vary.

This is the current code I'm using

```
async function addStringToTable(string, uuid) {
    // Save the input string to the database
    try{
        await UserText.create({
            userText_field: { [Sequelize.Op.eq]: string },
            uuidv4: { [Sequelize.Op.eq]: uuid }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Also is there something else I need to watch out for?

Thank you

Comment: The sequelize operators are for `WHERE` clauses, and don't really play a direct role in protecting against SQL injection, apart from allowing you to construct some more advanced queries without reverting to raw text. I'm not sure what that code/query would do when run?

Comment: It would save the user input into a database, and uuid would be used to track changes made by the user the text (*user input*) on each "testing" of the text/input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the beauty of ORM's. even without using extra syntax. Basically just writing is equivalent to your syntax

```
await UserText.create({
            userText_field: {  string },
            uuidv4: {  uuid }
        });
```

This automatically prevents sql injection. Its equivalent to prepared queries, which you would use in case of writing raw sql queries. But for sequalize(and any other ORM I know) it is done automatically with every query, no special syntax needed. You can also confirm that by logging query which this sequalize code outputs

Comment: thanks, just asking to be sure, are you saying I don't need the `Sequalize.Op.eq` at all?

Comment: @WeAreDoomed Yep its not needed at all, produces same result as yours. And any code written with Sequalize will be protected from sql injection

Comment: @WeAreDoomed Oh 1 quick correction, when directly defining, you do not need object braces {}. Just write userText_field: string.
Let me know if this answers your question or anything else interests you

Comment: Hah, I have a bunch of other questions, but I think that cover this question, thanks :)